# Alignment to left

Tags: math-mode

I have three equal:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
P_{N_1}(t) = e^{10 \cdot (t-1)} \\ P_{N_2}(t) = (0.9 + 0.1 \cdot t)^{100} \\ P_{N_3}(t) = \frac{\frac{5}{6}}{1-\frac{1}{6}t}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
```

and I would like have it  alignment to left. Is it possible? Because the last equation is moved to right, I don't know why...

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Remember that you can accept answers if they solve your issues. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use the `multlined` environment to do that, but `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&P_{N_1}(t) = e^{10 \cdot (t-1)} \\ &P_{N_2}(t) = (0.9 + 0.1 \cdot t)^{100} \\ &P_{N_3}(t) = \frac{\frac{5}{6}}{1-\frac{1}{6}t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]